# AutoFac Lifetime scopes for Isolated Azure Functions

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, autofac, azure-functions-isolated

We are looking to migrate several existing Azure Function apps that use AutoFac for DI from the in-process model to the isolated model.

As part of our current apps, we have some code taken from [this AutoFac documentation](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/azurefunctions.html) to handle management of AutoFac lifetime scopes. However, the interface `IJobActivatorEx` (and presumably runtime behavior) used in the article comes from the package `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host`. In [Microsoft's Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-dotnet-to-isolated-model?tabs=net8) for Upgrading to the isolated model, they state

> Your isolated worker model application should not reference any packages in the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.* namespaces or Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions. If you have any remaining references to these, they should be removed.

How do you establish the lifetime scope for AutoFac when running in the Isolated model? Is is still necessary to have code to establish the lifetime scope in our app or can this be removed and is no longer necessary?  If it is still necessary to establish the lifetime scope in the isolated runtime, how can I do it without `IJobActivatorEx` ?

At present, our app Program.cs look like this

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
.ConfigureServices(services => {
  //is this code in ConfigurServices() still necessary 
  //in an isolated function app in .net 6 or later?
  services.AddScoped<LifetimeScopeWrapper>();                
  services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(typeof(IJobActivator), typeof(AutofacJobActivator)));
  services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(typeof(IJobActivatorEx), typeof(AutofacJobActivator)));
});
```

Additional references
https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#asp-net-core-3-0-and-generic-hosting

Comment: I don't work with Azure functions, but [this part of the doc you linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-dotnet-to-isolated-model?tabs=net8#programcs-file) seems to indicate you set things up like an ASP.NET Core app. If you haven't tried that, try it. Autofac has ASP.NET doc. If you have tried and it doesn't work, maybe update your question to include exactly what didn't work.

Comment: @TravisIllig we have AutoFac working in the app using `hostBuilder.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())` which is now the AutoFac docs for .NET core 3.x have it set. The question I was trying to ask does this setup still need the IJobActivatorEx  parts from in-process function apps or can that be removed altogether?